# How to Move and Jump in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a First Person Shooter Game and am currently working on the jumping. I am using animation to jump as I have struggled with gravity before. However my problem is that my player cannot move if my jump script is attached to the player as well as the movement. However I know that it has nothing to do with the scripts as both scripts work but not simultaneously.

I believe it has something to do with the animation. There are 3 parts to the animation, Base, Running and Jump. If the player is moving the running animation is active, if the player has pressed the space bar then the jump animation is active. Jump animation is prioritised.

Is there any reason why the player cannot move and jump?

Here is the codes and animation controller:

Animation and Jump

```
public class Jump : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool run;
    public float speed;
    public GameObject player;
    public Animator dgbanim;
    public bool jump;
    public float rejump;
    public float rejumper;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        speed = 50;
        run = false;
        jump = false;
        rejumper = 0;
        rejump = 0;

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        if (jump == false && Input.GetKey("space")) { dgbanim.SetBool("Jump", true); jump = true; rejump = 21; }
        if (rejump > 0) { rejump = rejump - 1; }
        if(rejump == 0) { jump = false; dgbanim.SetBool("Jump", false); }

        if (Input.GetKey("w") || Input.GetKey("s") || Input.GetKey("a") || Input.GetKey("d") || Input.GetKey("up") || Input.GetKey("down") || Input.GetKey("left") || Input.GetKey("right")) { run = true; }


        if (run == true) { dgbanim.SetBool("Running", true); run = false; }
        else if (run == false) { dgbanim.SetBool("Running", false); }
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        //if (collision.gameObject.tag != "EnemyBullets") { jump = true; rejump = 0; }
        if (collision.gameObject.tag != "EnemyBullets") { jump = false; }

    }
}
```

Movement

```
public class Movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject player;
    public float speed;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        speed = 50;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        player.transform.Translate(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speed * Time.deltaTime, 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your animator have ‘apply root motion’ checked and its taking movement from animations rather than code, try unchecking it.

Answer (score 0):

Animation can control some properties of a GameObject, such as the position. If you try to edit a GameObject's position in a script but an animation controls the position, the animation will override the script's changes to the position.

To see if this is the problem, you can open the animation window and select your player. If the player's position (in the inspector) is red, then the animation is controlling it.

I know of 2 ways to fix this:

Method 1 (not recommended): Edit the animation to move the root bone instead of the player

Most character models have a GameObject called "Armature" or "root" as a child. The position of your character should not be in the animation. If you need to move the character up in your animation, you can animate the "Armature" or "root" GameObject. In the screenshot below, note that in the animation window you don't see "PlayerPref: position" but instead see "Armature: position". This allows my movement script to move PlayerPref without the animation overriding the position.
[image]

Method 2 (recommended): Use the physics engine to jump

In your animation, don't make the player jump. Instead make the player "jump in place" i.e. maybe swing arms upward as if jumping but don't actually move upward. Just like Method 1, your animation should not set the player's position. The easiest way to do this is to click on "player: position" in the animation window and press delete.

Add a Rigidbody to your character. In your script:

```
private Rigidbody rig;
...
void Start(){
    rig = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
...
}
```

In your script when you trigger jumping, you can add `rig.AddForce(jumpPower * transform.up);`. This will make the physics system handle the jumping. If the player is jumping but there is something above, the physics engine will stop the player. With animation, the player will jump through any obstacles.